# How can I get the Author info from CKAN?

Tags: api, ckan

I'm looking for all the information that ckan api can provide.

This is one of my result

```
[5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cache_last_updated] => 
                            [package_id] => 86dc2555-0e06-45be-aa2f-911d9431d29a
                            [webstore_last_updated] => 
                            [id] => 054d4e12-d07f-41bc-a7d3-3c2d8b2882fe
                            [size] => 
                            [state] => active
                            [last_modified] => 2016-08-15T18:30:53.146250
                            [hash] => 
                            [description] => Lista das 4.617 espécies nativas brasileiras avaliadas quanto ao risco de extinção - recorte temporal de 2012.
                            [format] => PDF
                            [mimetype_inner] => 
                            [url_type] => upload
                            [mimetype] => 
                            [cache_url] => 
                            [name] => Lista de espécies avaliadas - Livro Vermelho - 2013 - PDF
                            [created] => 2016-01-29T11:43:50.555625
                            [url] => http://ckan.jbrj.gov.br/dataset/86dc2555-0e06-45be-aa2f-911d9431d29a/resource/054d4e12-d07f-41bc-a7d3-3c2d8b2882fe/download/especiesavaliadaslv2013.pdf
                            [webstore_url] => 
                            [position] => 0
                            [revision_id] => c2903e9a-4587-4a1b-9b7f-1702e91d01f3
                            [resource_type] => 
                        )
```

I could not see the author field there, does someone knows how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Your data seems to come from a *resource*. In CKAN, resources don't carry ownership information. Instead, resources are attached to *packages* (see the `package_id` field), which in turn are linked to *organizations* (via their `organization` field). A package's organization is usually the source of the data, but a package also has information about its maintainer and possibly other people related to the data.